# RabbitMQ message storage and consumption

Tags: rabbitmq

I am new to RabbitMQ. In RabbitMQ once the message is consumed by a consumer will it still be available in the queue ? Can a single message from a particular queue be consumed by multiple consumers ? Unlike Kafka where message are stored in a file system how is it stored in RabbitMq ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can a single message from a particular queue be consumed by multiple consumers ?

Yes it very much possible, you can archive this by using fanout exchange. There are various type of Exchanges.

**Direct:** One to one, it's will vanish the message once delivered to consumer and you can handle the ack mode manually or auto. A direct exchange delivers messages to queues based on the message routing key.

**Fanout:** One to many, one message can be revived by multiple listener. A fanout exchange routes messages to all of the queues that are bound to it and the routing key is ignored

**Topic:** Topic exchanges route messages to one or many queues based on matching between a message routing key and the pattern that was used to bind a queue to an exchange

More on Exchange [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html):

> Unlike Kafka where message are stored in a file system how is it stored in RabbitMq ?

By default RabbitMQ will store messages in memory, if you want you can enable the message [persistence](https://www.rabbitmq.com/persistence-conf.html) and HA Polity(for mirroring) as an optional config based on your requirement. However it's coming with the cost of performance, it will reduce your throughput by throttling(I/O operation involve).

[image]